# What is the most efficient way to do two different joins on the same two dataframes in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to compare two dataframes to look for new records and updated records, which in turn will be used to create a third dataframe.  I am using Pyspark 2.4.3

As I come from a SQL background (ASE), my initial thought would be to do a left join to find new records and a != on a hash of all the columns to find updates:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM Todays_Data a
Left Join Yesterdays_PK_And_Hash b on a.pk = b.pk
WHERE (b.pk IS NULL) --finds new records
OR (b.hashOfColumns != HASHBYTES('md5',<converted and concatenated columns>)) --updated records
```

I have been playing around with Pyspark and have come up with a script that achieves the results I am after:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import md5, concat_ws, col, lit

sc = SparkContext("local", "test App")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sp = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test App") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = sp.createDataFrame(
    [("Fred", "Smith", "16ba5519cdb13f99e087473e4faf3825"),  # hashkey here is created based on  YOB of 1973.  To test for an update
     ("Fred", "Davis", "253ab75676cdbd73b874c97a62d27608"),
     ("Barry", "Clarke", "cc3baaa05a1146f2f8cf0a743c9ab8c4")],
    ["First_name", "Last_name", "hashkey"]
)

df_a = sp.createDataFrame(
    [("Fred", "Smith", "Adelaide", "Doctor", 1971),
     ("Fred", "Davis", "Melbourne", "Baker", 1970),
     ("Barry", "Clarke", "Sydney", "Scientist", 1975),
     ("Jane", "Hall", "Sydney", "Dentist", 1980)],
    ["First_name", "Last_name", "City", "Occupation", "YOB"]
)

df_a = df_a.withColumn("hashkey", md5(concat_ws("", *df_a.columns)))

df_ins = df_a.alias('a').join(df.alias('b'), (col('a.First_name') == col('b.First_name')) &
                              (col('a.Last_name') == col('b.Last_name')), 'left_anti') \
    .select(lit("Insert").alias("_action"), 'a.*') \
    .dropDuplicates()

df_up = df_a.alias('a').join(df.alias('b'), (col('a.First_name') == col('b.First_name')) &
                             (col('a.Last_name') == col('b.Last_name')) &
                             (col('a.hashkey') != col('b.hashkey')), 'inner') \
    .select(lit("Update").alias("_action"), 'a.*') \
    .dropDuplicates()

df_delta = df_ins.union(df_up).sort("YOB")

df_delta = df_delta.drop("hashkey")

df_delta.show(truncate=False)
```

What this produces is my final delta as such:

```
+-------+----------+---------+--------+----------+----+
|_action|First_name|Last_name|City    |Occupation|YOB |
+-------+----------+---------+--------+----------+----+
|Update |Fred      |Smith    |Adelaide|Doctor    |1971|
|Insert |Jane      |Hall     |Sydney  |Dentist   |1980|
+-------+----------+---------+--------+----------+----+
```

While I am getting the results I am after, I am unsure how efficient the above code is.

Ultimately in the end, I would like to run similar patterns against datasets into the 100's of million records.

Is there anyway to make this more efficient?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you explored broadcast join? Your join statements could be problematic if you have 100M + records. If the dataset B is smaller, this would the tiny modification I would try:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import md5, concat_ws, col, lit, broadcast

sc = SparkContext("local", "test App")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

sp = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("test App") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = sp.createDataFrame(
    [("Fred", "Smith", "16ba5519cdb13f99e087473e4faf3825"),  # hashkey here is created based on  YOB of 1973.  To test for an update
     ("Fred", "Davis", "253ab75676cdbd73b874c97a62d27608"),
     ("Barry", "Clarke", "cc3baaa05a1146f2f8cf0a743c9ab8c4")],
    ["First_name", "Last_name", "hashkey"]
)

df_a = sp.createDataFrame(
    [("Fred", "Smith", "Adelaide", "Doctor", 1971),
     ("Fred", "Davis", "Melbourne", "Baker", 1970),
     ("Barry", "Clarke", "Sydney", "Scientist", 1975),
     ("Jane", "Hall", "Sydney", "Dentist", 1980)],
    ["First_name", "Last_name", "City", "Occupation", "YOB"]
)

df_a = df_a.withColumn("hashkey", md5(concat_ws("", *df_a.columns)))

df_ins = df_a.alias('a').join(broadcast(df.alias('b')), (col('a.First_name') == col('b.First_name')) &
                              (col('a.Last_name') == col('b.Last_name')), 'left_anti') \
    .select(lit("Insert").alias("_action"), 'a.*') \
    .dropDuplicates()

df_up = df_a.alias('a').join(broadcast(df.alias('b')), (col('a.First_name') == col('b.First_name')) &
                             (col('a.Last_name') == col('b.Last_name')) &
                             (col('a.hashkey') != col('b.hashkey')), 'inner') \
    .select(lit("Update").alias("_action"), 'a.*') \
    .dropDuplicates()

df_delta = df_ins.union(df_up).sort("YOB")
```

Maybe rewriting the code cleanly would be easier to follow too.

@Ash, from a readability standpoint, you could do a couple of things:

1. Use variables
2. Use functions.
3. Use pep-8 guiding style as much as possible. (ex: no more than 80 chars in a line)

```
joinExpr = (col('a.First_name') == col('b.First_name')) &
                              (col('a.Last_name') == col('b.Last_name')
joinType = 'left_anti'
df_up = df_a.alias('a').join(broadcast(df.alias('b')), joinExpr) &
                             (col('a.hashkey') != col('b.hashkey')), joinType) \
    .select(lit("Update").alias("_action"), 'a.*') \
    .dropDuplicates()
```

This is still long, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks.  I've just run a quick test using a broadcast join on a reasonable data set (10M records) and that has seen a 15% time saving.  As for messy code, I know I rushed it (late Friday before the pub called), but am also curious to understand what you specifically inferring.  Is it the naming conventions and lack of comments? (I am honestly asking - always trying to improve my readability)